# jQuery next: only next, not all next classes

Tags: jquery

I need to remove a class on the current given class AND THEN look for the next element and set that same class.

So I have 4 light-grey circles, the first one is dark-grey. On click of the button I want the first one to turn light-grey and seconds one dark-grey.
[image]

My jQuery and HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#next-usp").click(function(){    
  $('.usp-container-nav').removeClass('grey-bg').next('.usp-container-nav').addClass('grey-bg');
 });
</script>

HTML
<div class="usp-nav-mobile">
 <a id="nav-mob-1" class="usp-container-nav grey-bg"></a>
 <a id="nav-mob-2" class="usp-container-nav"></a>
 <a id="nav-mob-3" class="usp-container-nav"></a>
 <a id="nav-mob-4" class="usp-container-nav"></a>
</div>

<a id="next-usp"></a>
```

My problem is that it selects ALL `.usp-container-nav`'s, but I need it to select only the next one and remove class on current one.

Comment: Change `$('.usp-container-nav').removeClass('grey-bg')` to `$('.usp-container-nav.grey-bg').removeClass('grey-bg')`

Comment: Cool this works, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're essentially doing:

```
$('.usp-container-nav').next('.usp-container-nav')
```

where

```
$('.usp-container-nav')
```

selects *all* of the nav items.  You want to select only the active nav item, remove the active from that, move to next and add active to the new item:

```
$('.usp-container-nav.grey-bg').next('.usp-container-nav')
```

Updated snippet:

```js
$("#next-usp").click(function(){    
  $('.usp-container-nav.grey-bg').removeClass('grey-bg').next('.usp-container-nav').addClass('grey-bg');
 });
```

```css
.grey-bg { color:red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="usp-nav-mobile">
 <a id="nav-mob-1" class="usp-container-nav grey-bg">1</a>
 <a id="nav-mob-2" class="usp-container-nav">2</a>
 <a id="nav-mob-3" class="usp-container-nav">3</a>
 <a id="nav-mob-4" class="usp-container-nav">4</a>
</div>

<a id="next-usp">next</a>
```

---

As pointed out in one of the other answers, you'll get an issue when it gets to the end, but how you fix that depends on your requirements - should it loop or disable the next button?

Answer (score 1):

Incase you want it to return to 1 after 4 , you can use this:

```
var counter = 1;
$("#next-usp").click(function(){  
if(counter == 4){
$('#nav-mob-'+counter).removeClass('grey-bg');
counter = 1;
$('#nav-mob-'+counter).addClass('grey-bg');
} else {
$('#nav-mob-'+counter).removeClass('grey-bg');
$('#nav-mob-'+(counter+1)).addClass('grey-bg');
counter++
}
});
```

Comment: All other answers were exactly what I asked for, but this is even more! Awesome solution, I'm gonna use this, thanks!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:first` to select only the first next li:

```
 $("#next-usp").click(function(){    
    $('.usp-container-nav').removeClass('grey-bg').next('.usp-container-nav:first').addClass('grey-bg');
 });
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, it only removes the grey-bg from the first, but doesn't add it to the next.

Comment: @Sybrentjuh That's strange as it does add it to the next in this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6udm9bft/

Comment: hmm that's strange, it indeed does. The only problem is, i thought it would iteratie to the 3rd and 4rd aswell. Is that not how .next works? Because when you press the next button multiple times it should work aswell.

Comment: @Sybrentjuh Next doesn't iterate, it just select the next items. If you want to iterate, you could use a counter like here: https://jsfiddle.net/6udm9bft/1/

Comment: It adds it to the next of *all* the selected elements in the first selector.

Comment: @matthias_h updated your fiddle to show what's going on - it only updates it the first time https://jsfiddle.net/x7rp63v2/ because `$(".nav")` selects all the navs then `.next(":first")` selects the first one (of the next list) which is the 2nd one as all items are in the first list.  In the updated fiddle, click `next` more than once.